# Network attached external harddrive from another computer

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive

I have a server that is setup in raid. It is on the same network as my main computer. I would like to have some of the memory on my server to act as a network attached drive on my main computer. Basically, I want it to be a new data drive (similar two C:\, but 2nd drives are mostly E:). That way, I can reformat my main computer without loosing any important data. And the data that is saved (on server E:\ drive) is secured via raid mirroring.

Comment: +1(5) from developer. Keep going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, which versions and editions of Windows?

As a developer, I see many issues with this solution.

"Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Well, don't do that."

1. network applications cannot use mapped drives but only UNC network shares. See for ex., http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AccessingMappedNetworkDrivesViaASPNETInIIS6.aspx
2. By mapping drive to external share you will break all uses of impersonation (impersonation can be used only on the same machine) that would require to reconfigure for delegation
3. other issues

Comment: I am running windows 7 (dev machine) and windows server 2008 (backup machine, raid).

Comment: How would you suggest I go about securing my code/projects on my raid server?

Comment: Hi, Paul, I was banned from site and could not answer. Are you done?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to map a share from your main computer to the workstation. First create a share on the server on the drive you want to save data to.  Then on the workstation type:

```
net use * \\myserver\myshare /u:myserveruser
```

If these are not in a domain you will either need to have the same username on both or specify the username in the command.  You will be prompted for the password.  You can then backup your data to the new drive (it will show up as either the next available drive letter or as the last avaialable drive letter depending on your windows version)

Answer (score 0):

You can have iSCSI shares setup on the server, which can be mounted on the local machine, and will appear as a built in drive.  AS far as programs or the OS is concerned it is a local drive.  This may also be overkill for you situation.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 (and Vista) drive letters are considered legacy for supporting older apps that require a mapped drive.  To make a friendly link to network shared drives, open Explorer, click on Computer.  You should see your local drives.  Right click on the blank area in the window and choose "add a network location" and type the server and share name like so:

`\\servername\sharename\`

If you have not shared out a folder on the server, then:  On the server make a user account with the same username and password as you log into your Windows 7 machine with.  That way it shouldn't prompt you on "workgroup based" computers to access network shares.

Typically you would decide on the server what folder you want to share out, right click and click "share with" and choose the username you just added and give full read/write permissions.

then in your development environment when saving data, navigate to "Computer" and you should see the new network location you added above (it's kinda like a shortcut).  Older apps may not support network paths and may require drive mappings like Jim B says, but vgv8 is also correct and his link to Scott Hanselmen... well Scott's a development god so I basically do whatever he says.  Awesome to see him teach in person, fun guy.